# django tastypie patch gives me a "500" error

Tags: python, django, tastypie

it showing the error "error_message": "invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''" 
I am getting this error for patch request to a user resource. my user model is

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    VIA_FACEBOOK = 1
    VIA_GOOGLE = 2

    SIGN_IN_TYPES = (
        (VIA_FACEBOOK,'facebook'),
        (VIA_GOOGLE,'google')
    )

    MALE =  1
    FEMALE = 0

    GENDERA_TYPES = (
        (FEMALE,'female'),
        (MALE,'male')
         )

    SINGLE_ACCOUNT_USER = 0
    JOINT_ACCOUNT_USER = 1


    USER_TYPES = (
        (SINGLE_ACCOUNT_USER,'single_accout_user'),
        (JOINT_ACCOUNT_USER,'joint_accout_user')

    )
    first_name = models.CharField(blank = True, max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50,null=True )
    last_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50,null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False,unique=True,max_length=100)
    sign_in_via = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=SIGN_IN_TYPES, default=0)
    mobile = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=10,null=True )
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    profile_pic_url = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=300,null=True)
    background_pic_url = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=300,null=True)
    gender = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True,choices=GENDERA_TYPES,null=True)
    user_type = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=False,choices=USER_TYPES,default=0)
    details = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=500,null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

MY user resource script is :

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'put','delete']
        authorization = Authorization()
        include_resource_uri = True
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = Authentication()
        filtering = {
            'id': ALL,
            'email': ALL,
            'user_type': ALL,
            'mobile': ALL,
            'created_at': ALL,
        }
        excludes = ['created_on','password','last_login','sign_in_via']
```

GET and POST are working fine, but PATCH and PUT methods are not working.
i am making a request using Postman
so, for an PATCH request (`http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/user_api/user/14/?format=json`) body will be

```
{
  "background_pic_url": "h/h",
  "last_name":"sdfsd"
}
```

then i am getting an 500, internal server error. stack trace is

```
{
  "error_message": "invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''",
  "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):

  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 220, in wrapper
    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 460, in dispatch_detail
    return self.dispatch('detail', request, **kwargs)

  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 483, in dispatch
    response = method(request, **kwargs)

  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 1669, in patch_detail
    bundle = self.full_dehydrate(bundle)

  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 885, in full_dehydrate
    data[field_name] = field_object.dehydrate(bundle, for_list=for_list)

  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\fields.py\", line 146, in dehydrate
    return self.convert(current_object)

  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\fields.py\", line 255, in convert
    return int(value)\n\nValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''"

}
```

and for PUT request, body will be

```
{
  "email":"a@a.com",
  "first_name":"a",
  "middle_name":"b",
  "last_name":"c",
    "mobile":"1234567890",
    "details":"nothing",
    "profile_pic_url":"n/n",
    "background_pic_url":"v/v",
    "sign_in_via":"1",
    "dob":"2017-01-29",
    "user_type":"1",
    "gender":"2"
}
```

for this also i am getting 500 internal server error. the stack trace is :

```
{
    "error_message": "'dict' object has no attribute 'first_name'",
    "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):

  File       \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 220, in   wrapper
    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File    \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 460, in dispatch_detail
    return self.dispatch('detail', request, **kwargs)

  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 483, in dispatch
    response = method(request, **kwargs)

  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 1472, in put_detail
    updated_bundle = self.obj_update(bundle=bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))

  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 2226, in obj_update
    bundle = self.full_hydrate(bundle)

  File \"C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tastypie\\resources.py\", line 939, in full_hydrate
    setattr(bundle.obj, field_object.attribute, value)\n\nAttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'first_name'"

}
```

i have no clue why im getting these errors.

Comment: show us the code of the controller that is handling the requsest

Comment: hey @AminEtesamian, because im using tastypie, PUT, PATCH, GET, POST wont need any code. the resource will handle these requests automatically. and im not using any helper methods for these requests.

Answer (score 1):

Your PUT body has:

```
{
  ...
  "user_type": "1",
  "gender": "2"
}
```

and your model fields:

```
gender = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True,choices=GENDERA_TYPES,null=True)
user_type = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=False,choices=USER_TYPES,default=0)
```

so you must make the PUT/PATCH request with numbers too like you specified in the model

```
{
  ...
  "user_type": 1,
  "gender": 2
}
```

wich is valid in JSON.

Hope this helps.

Regards!